# Simple operations with TCP/IP Header bits

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, tcp, raw-sockets

I have two doubts related to operations with bits:

The first one is the >> operator. As far as I have read, this operator does this

0001 0000 >> 4  -->  0000 0001 or this 1111 0001, not sure if it fills with 1s or 0s

So I have this code:

```
version_ihl = iph[0]
version = version_ihl >> 4
ihl = version_ihl & 0xF
```

Let's say IP Version is 4: 0100 and IHL is 5: 0101

If I do the version = version_ihl >> 4, the result would be

0100 0101 ---> 0000 0100 in case the operator >> doesn't fill with 1, which I have read it actually does, so instead of IP Version = 4 would be 1111 0100 which is not 4 at all.

The second thing is this line, how to calculate ihl with `ihl = version_ihl & 0xF`

The final result is 5, so 0000 0101 and as far as I know, that operator does a mask of all 1s, so 0100 0101 would remain the same. So the two questions are :

1.How do you obtain from 0100 0101 with >> 4 operation the result 0000 0100 if >> is supposed to fill with 1s¿?

2.How do you obtain from 0100 0101 the result 0000 0101 with the & 0xF mask¿?

The code I posted worked perfectly right, so the solution is there, I just want to know why it works like that. Thank you in advance, hope someone could through some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `>>` operator does not "fill" anything with anything.  Integers in Python behave as though they have an infinite number of leading zeros (nonnegative integers) or ones (negative integers).  Right-shifting simply drops the *n* least significant bits.
2. `0xF` is the same as `0b1111`, which in turn is the same as `0b00001111`.  You are only masking the least significant nybble with ones.

Since you asked for more detail:

1. You started with `0100 0101` and right-shifted by four.   That's *exactly equivalent* to starting with `0000 0100 0101` and right-shifting by four, which gives you `0000 0100`.  That, in turn, is the same as `0100`.
2. You started with `0100 0101` and masked with `0xF`.  `0xF` is just `1111`, which is the same as `0000 1111`.  So you get `0000 0101`, or just `0101`

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer doesn't help me much you must be very used to this but I am new on this matter and really, cannot take a single hint out of your answer. 
It the explanation would fit the scenario telling what I receive and what I obtain would be great and so with the mask.

Comment: @user3515313: I added more detail.